# How to get the timezone offset for a specific timezone?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, utc, dayjs

I need to sort cities based on their timezone (as TZ identifiers). To do so, the most natural way I found was to compare the offset of these timezones to UTC (but I am open to any solution).

[`Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) seemed to be the perfect candidate, I took the example from the docs:

```js
const myDate = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT+07:00')
console.log(myDate.getTimezoneOffset())
```

The comment of the example states

> // Expected output: your local timezone offset in minutes
> // (e.g., -120). NOT the timezone offset of the date object.

I am trying to process this but I simply do not understand what `Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()` if it **always** returns the local offset to UTS, no matter the date it is applied to.

If the above is correct (which seems really weird, taken that `getTimezoneOffset()` is applied to a date object), how can I get the UTC offset of a date object?

I will ultimately use [Day.js](https://day.js.org/) to manipulate my dates, so the final code I expected to work (but it does not per the above) was

```
console.log(dayjs().tz('America/Los_Angeles').toDate().getTimezoneOffset())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS Dates don't contain timezone information, `getTimezoneOffset()` gives you the local timezone offset at a particular date:

```js
let myDate = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT+07:00')
console.log(myDate.getTimezoneOffset())

myDate = new Date('August 19, 2023 23:15:30 GMT+03:00')
console.log(myDate.getTimezoneOffset())

/* gives for my region (timezone in the strings doesn't affect this):
-180
-120
*/
```

Parse your date strings directly.
If you want to get timezone offsets by a timezone's name:

```js
function getTimezoneOffset(timeZone){
  const str = new Date().toLocaleString('en', {timeZone, timeZoneName: 'longOffset'});
  const [_,h,m] = str.match(/([+-]\d+):(\d+)$/) || [, '+00', '00'];
  return h * 60 + (h > 0 ? +m : -m);
}

'America/Los_Angeles America/New_York Asia/Kolkata Pacific/Marquesas Etc/UTC'.match(/\S+/g).forEach(tz => 
  console.log(tz, getTimezoneOffset(tz))
);
```

To parse from a date string:

```js
function getTimezoneOffset(str){
  const [_,h,m] = str.match(/([+-]\d+):(\d+)$/) || [, '+00', '00'];
  return h * 60 + (h > 0 ? +m : -m);
}

console.log(getTimezoneOffset('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT+07:00'))
```

Comment: *`getTimezoneOffset()` gives you the local timezone offset at a particular date* This is the part I do not understand. `getTimezoneOffset()` is applied to a date object (which can be in, say, GMT+8), but it gives anyway the offset vs. the local timezone? So it does not matter which date object it is applied to?

Comment: @WoJ for example i had GMT+3 in 1975, now i have GMT+2 in my region. so this doesn't relate to the date on which you call getTimezoneOffset(). Updated my answer with a snippet. dont hesitate to accept and upvote, thanks

Comment: @WoJ—an ECMAScript *Date* object doesn't have a timezone. It's only data property is an offset from 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC in milliseconds, called a [*time value*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-time-values-and-time-range). When a timestamp with offset is parsed, it's resolved to a time value so effectively becomes UTC. The timezone or offset in the original timestamp is not stored as part of the *Date*.

Comment: @RobG: thank you for the clarification. In that case, if there is a difference between the same day in 1973 and 2023, would this mean that **the offset changed** in the meantime (either because DST was introduced/abandoned, or the definition of the timezone changed)?

Comment: @WoJ yes, as i've explained in the first snippet

Comment: @WoJ—yes. Places change their offset for reasons other than daylight saving, e.g. offsets for major cities in the 1800s.